# Functionality of storyboard segues

Tags: memory-management, xcode6, segue, viewcontroller

I am using Xcode 6 and my project is in ARC mode. In my project, I hook up segues in the storyboard. So far I believe I only used the 'Push' segues. I was wondering, when I do activate this segue, does the previous view controller get deallocated? For example, i am using a 'Push' segue to go from a login screen to the home screen and I want to make sure the log in screen is not hanging around. If it is, how do I deallocate it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deallocate it, you can release something in viewDidDisapper.`

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    //TODO: release something
}
```

`
You don't need to manage in the ARC mode ViewController destroyed, only need to handle something need to manually shut down or release, such as NSTimer.